# How to add a gradient component to a custom block

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I can't find any useful information in Gutenberg Handbook. [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/#block-gradient-presets) is information about adding gradients, but it only works for some core blocks.

I use `ColorPalette` to create colors (or to use the color picker) but still don't know how to use gradients. I also found `PanelColorSettings` but still without success.

I am looking for instructions/documentation on how to add this component:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The documentation for that control does not exist at this time. Instructions have not been written yet. It is an experimental component.**

---

You need to use an appropriate control in your blocks Edit component.

Note that these are very new components, their design will likely change, *it should be considered experimental and unstable*.

There is the `GradientPicker` component, https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/components/src/gradient-picker/index.js

And `ColorGradientControl` https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/26e4d59e6fd3ed78d0213d60abca31c6dc1fa9cb/packages/block-editor/src/components/colors-gradients/control.js

```
        <ColorGradientControl
            { ...otherProps }
            onColorChange={ onChange }
            colorValue={ value }
            gradients={ [] }
            disableCustomGradients={ true }
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found support for custom block, it really helps.

```
supports: {
    color: {
        // This also enables text and background UI controls.
        gradients: true; // Enable gradients UI control.
    }
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/